# How i use url_for for route beginning with slug?

Tags: python, flask

I have this route on my app:

```
@app.route('/<buildingSlug>/members/', methods=("GET", "POST"))
```

and I want to use url_for for that route, but I can't find a way

```
<form action="{{ url_for('members') }}" method="POST">
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<form action="{{ url_for('members', buildingSlug='yourBuildingSlugValue') }}" method="POST">
```

Comment: Although the best way for multiple routes is with blueprints: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look back at [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for): it takes the name of the *method*, the "endpoint", and doesn't care about what url you've assigned for that endpoint with the `app.route` decorator, which is the whole point of `url_for`.

The [tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#url-building) has several examples of using `url_for`:

```
>>> from flask import Flask, url_for
>>> app = Flask(__name__)
>>> @app.route('/')
... def index(): pass
...
>>> @app.route('/login')
... def login(): pass
...
>>> @app.route('/user/<username>')
... def profile(username): pass
...
>>> with app.test_request_context():
...  print url_for('index')
...  print url_for('login')
...  print url_for('login', next='/')
...  print url_for('profile', username='John Doe')
...
/
/login
/login?next=/
/user/John%20Doe
```

It even gives reasons why `url_for` should be used (and, by extension, what it's good at doing):

> Why would you want to build URLs instead of hard-coding them into your templates? There are three good reasons for this:
>
> Reversing is often more descriptive than hard-coding the URLs. More importantly, it allows you to change URLs in one go, without having to remember to change URLs all over the place.
> URL building will handle escaping of special characters and Unicode data transparently for you, so you don’t have to deal with them.
> If your application is placed outside the URL root (say, in /myapplication instead of /), url_for() will handle that properly for you.

The most important thing to take away from this is that `url_for` is not dependent on the URL constructed with `app.route`.